# ImportError : Cannot import name 'model_urls' from 'torchvision.models.vgg'

Tags: python, import, pytorch, torch, torchvision

I want to import 'model_urls' from 'torchvision.models.vgg' :

[image]

As apparently 'model_urls' is no longer available for some versions of torchvision, I got the below error :

[image]

Downgrading the version of torchvision to 0.13 and 0.12 does not seem to help.
So what is the solution or appropriate version for torchvision to suppress the mentioned error?